# Is it possible that mongodb's $project return an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible for MongoDb's $project aggregation operator to restructure the document to an array ?

Here is what I did so far:

```
var pipeline = [];
var project = {
    $project : {
        x: "$_id", 
        y: "$y" ,
        _id : 0
    }
};
pipeline.push(project);
model.aggregate( pipeline, callback);
```

This gives me output of form:

```
[
  { 
   x: '...',
   y: '...'
  }
 ....
]
```

I would like to have:

```
[
   ['..','..']
   ....
]
```

I can easily restructure the output by iterating it, but really curious to know if aggregate itself could return array instead of object.

Answer (score 4):

You could try with the $push operator.

For example,
if you had documents like:

```
{ _id: <something>, y: 5 }
```

In the mongo shell, if you type

```
db.model.aggregate( [ { $group: { _id: null, newArrayField: { $push: {  x: "$_id", y: "$y"  } } } } ] )
```

You would get:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "newArrayField" : [
                {
                    "x" : ObjectId("5265dd479eb4b1d4289cf222"),
                    "y" : 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

For more information on $push operator, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/

Comment: Would like to have "result" : [ [ObjectId("5265dd479eb4b1d4289cf222"), 5] ]

Answer (score 1):

With MongoDB 3.2 you can [project array values](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#example-project-new-array-fields)

```
db.model.aggregate({
  $project: {arrayField: ['$_id', '$y']}
})
```

Comment: simple & working trick