# Behaviour of the project stage operator in projecting Arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My question is closely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501906/is-it-possible-that-mongodbs-project-return-an-array), but not similar.

I have a sample document in my collection:

```
db.t.insert({"a":1,"b":2});
```

My intent is to project a field named `combined` of type `array` with the values of both `a` and `b` together.`([1,2])`.

I simply try to aggregate with a `$project` stage:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$project:{"combined":[]}}
])
```

`MongoDB` throws an error: `disallowed field type Array in object expression`.

Which means a field cannot be projected as a array.

But when i use a `$cond` operator to project an array, the field gets projected.

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$project:{"combined":{$cond:[{$eq:[1,1]},["$a","$b"],"$a"]}}}
])
```

I get the o/p: `{"combined" : [ "$a", "$b" ] }`.

If you notice the output, the value of `a` and `b` are treated as if they were literals and not a field paths.

Can anyone please explain to me this behavior?, When i make the condition to fail,

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$project:{"combined":{$cond:[{$eq:[1,2]},["$a","$b"],"$a"]}}}
])
```

I get the expected output where `$a` is treated as a field path, since `$a` is not enclosed as an array element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into this before too and it's annoying, but it's actually working as documented for literal `["$a", "$b"]`; the first error about disallowed field type is...not as clear why it complains. You have to follow the description of the grammar of the `$project` stage spread out in the documentation, however. I'll try to do that here. Starting at [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/),

> The $project stage has the following prototype form:

```
{ $project: { <specifications> } }
```

and specifications can be one of the following:

```
1. <field> : <1 or true or 0 or false>
2. <field> : <expression>
```

What's an expression? From [aggregation expressions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions),

> Expressions can include field paths and system variables, literals, expression objects, and operator expressions.

What are each of those things? A field path/system variable should be familiar: it's a string literal prefixed with $ or $$. An expression object has the form

```
{ <field1>: <expression1>, ... }
```

while an operator expression has one of the forms

```
{ <operator>: [ <argument1>, <argument2> ... ] }

{ <operator>: <argument> }
```

for some enumerated list of values for `<operator>`.

What's an `<argument>`? The documentation isn't clear on it, but from my experience I think it's any expression, subject to the syntax rules of the given operator (examine the operator expression `"cond" : ...` in the question).

Arrays fit in only as containers for argument lists and as literals. Literals are literals - their content is not evaluated for field paths or system variables, which is why the array literal argument in the `$cond` ends up with the value `[ "$a", "$b" ]`. The expressions in the argument array are evaluated.

The first error about Array being a disallowed value type is a bit odd to me, since an array literal is a valid expression, so according to the documentation it can be a value in an object expression. I don't see any ambiguity in parsing it as part of an object expression, either. It looks like it's just a rule they made to make the parsing easier? You can "dodge" it using `$literal` to put in a constant array value:

```
db.collection.project([{ "$project" : { "combined" : { "$literal" : [1, 2] } } }])
```

I hope this helps explain why things work this way. I was surprised the first time I tried to do something like `[ "$a", "$b" ]` and it didn't work as I expected. It'd be nice if there were a feature to pack field paths into an array, at least. I've found uses for it when `$group`ing on ordered pairs of values, as well.

There's a JIRA ticket, [SERVER-8141](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8141), requesting an `$array` operator to help with cases like this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. I think, the one part on which the documentation can improve, is in introducing a section for each operator or at least for a pipeline stage,which states, how the pipeline syntax will get parsed and interpreted on the server, so that we may deduce those little things which are explicitly not mentioned in the document.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Helped me with my aggregation query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259171/mongo-aggregation-query-in-golang-with-mgo-driver