# mongo aggregation query with mgo driver

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mgo

I have the following query in mongodb:

```
db.devices.aggregate({
$match: {userId: "v73TuQqZykbxFXsWo", state: true}},
{
  $project: {
    userId: 1,
    categorySlug: 1,
    weight: { 
      $cond: [ 
        {"$or": [  
          {$eq: ["$categorySlug", "air_fryer"] }, 
          {$eq: ["$categorySlug", "iron"] } 
        ] }, 
      0, 1] } 
    } },  
    {$sort: {weight: 1}},
    { $limit : 10 }
);
```

I'm trying to write this in Go using the mgo driver but not able to wrap my head around this at all!

How do I translate this to a Go mgo query?

Comment: Just split each stage and use`bson.M{}` to wrap around each nest level of your query with quotation marks, something like: `match := bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"userId": "...", ...}}`, then `project := bson.M{"$project"...}`. Now use mgo driver `Pipe` with those, like `pipe := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{match, project})`, and finally retrieve the result with `pipe.All(&yourResultStruct)`. Read their docs of `Pipe` [here](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Pipe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The examples on the docs would be sufficient to get started. However, if you are not familiar with golang, the `$cond` part could be a bit tricky. See below example code:

```
    collection := session.DB("dbName").C("devices")

    stage_match := bson.M{"$match":bson.M{"userId":"v73TuQqZykbxFXsWo", "state": true}}

    condition_weight := []interface{}{bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{
                       bson.M{"$eq": []string{"$categorySlug", "air_fryer"}},
                       bson.M{"$eq": []string{"$categorySlug", "iron"}},
    }}, 0, 1}

    stage_project:= bson.M{"$project": bson.M{"userId":1, "categorySlug":1, "weight": condition_weight}}

    stage_sort := bson.M{"$sort": bson.M{"weight":1}}

    stage_limit := bson.M{"$limit": 10}

    pipe := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{stage_match, stage_project, stage_sort, stage_limit})
```

See also [mgo: type Pipe](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Pipe)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Yes, you got it right about not me not being able to correctly translate the various parts in the aggregation query. Kudos!

Comment: I needed to make a minor correction in the query on the lines of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686914/behaviour-of-the-project-stage-operator-in-projecting-arrays in order to make it work in my case. In stage_project, the 'weight' parameter needs to be defined as "weight": bson.M{"$literal": condition_weight}

Comment: thanks for answer that's a good practice to write illustrated aggregation query